# How to get the endpoint of a Line with a rotation in three,js?

Tags: vector, three.js

I'm trying to calculate the end of a Line with an rotation applied but can't seem to get it correct.

I'm currently trying it in the following way:

```js
function createLine(x, y, z, length, zrad, xrad) {
  var points = [
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(length / 8, length * 0.75, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, length, 0),
  ];

  var spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3(points);

  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff00f0,
  });

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  var splinePoints = spline.getPoints(numPoints);

  for (var i = 0; i < splinePoints.length; i++) {
    geometry.vertices.push(splinePoints[i]);
  }

  var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);

  line.position.x = x;
  line.position.y = y;
  line.position.z = z;

  line.rotateZ(zrad);
  line.rotateX(xrad);

  // This is probably not the proper way to store the length of the Line
  line.length = length;

  return line;
}

function splitLine(line) {
  var lines = [];

  var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, line.length, 0);
  vector.applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), line.rotation.z);
  vector.applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), line.rotation.x);

  var endPoint = vector.add(line.position);

  console.log(endPoint);

  lines.push(createLine(endPoint.x, endPoint.y, endPoint.z, line.length / 1.3, line.rotation.z - 45 * (Math.PI / 180), line.rotation.x - 45 * (Math.PI / 180))) //line.rotation.y - 45 * (Math.PI/180)));
  lines.push(createLine(endPoint.x, endPoint.y, endPoint.z, line.length / 1.3, line.rotation.z + 45 * (Math.PI / 180), line.rotation.x + 45 * (Math.PI / 180))) //line.rotation.y + 45 * (Math.PI/180)));

  return lines;
}
```

Where `var endPoint = vector.add(line.position);` gives the wrong position.
Curiously it gives the correct coordinates if the `line.rotation.x = 0`;